# How to resolve 'Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4" What should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Gemfile

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.10.12"
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker.git', :branch => 'master'
```

My app was working perfectly fine until I started working on a new application that required a ruby version 2.6.3 and I believe I accidently changed the ruby version.

```
% rvm list rubies
   ruby-2.6.3 [ missing bin/ruby ]
   ruby-2.7.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.3 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.7.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

It appears that my current ruby version is 2.7.4 but the application states my version is 2.6.3

Errors I am receiving:

`Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4`

I have tried following

- Bundle
- gem update bundle
- removing ruby and reinstalling it via homebrew

Comment: from your terminal type `rvm use 2.7.4 --default` to make it default and run the project again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gemsets to avoid accidentally changing ruby versions, but for now use the command:

```
rvm use 2.7.4 --default
```

https://rvm.io/gemsets/creating

in the project, you will need to create a yes gitignore file

```
.ruby-gemset ->
cool_project #project_name

.ruby-version ->
2.7.4 #project ruby version
```

after that, you will have a mini environment for each project and you will not accidentally spoil it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.